# python regex using re.compile and match

Tags: python, regex

```
eag = 'linux'
rpat = re.compile("^\s*%s\s*=\s*('.*\'')" % eag)
```

trying to grab `r'^LIN'` in a line in a text file, `linux = r'^LIN',`

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open (myfile, 'r')]
for line in lines:
    if re.match(rpat, line)
        matched = re.match(rpat,line)
        got_it = matched.group(1)
        # do something here
```

Not quite sure if my `rpat` is correct
There is some space in the front of linux then some space until = then some space r'^LIN',

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but when I am debugging regex I like to use this website.  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

```
re.compile("^\s*%s\s*=\s*(r'[^']+')" % re.escape(eag))
```

This matches the `r` as well, which you omitted.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = "linux = r'^LIN',"
>>> eag = 'linux'
>>> rpat = re.compile("^\s*%s\s*=\s*(r'[^']+')" % re.escape(eag))
>>> rpat.match(sample).group(1)
"r'^LIN'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is quite messy.

I have tried to fix it:

```
rpat = re.compile(r"^\s*%s\s*=\s*(r'.*')\s*" % eag)
```

Your forgot `r` to match `r'LIN'` and forgot about trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`rpat = re.compile("^\s*%s\s*=\s*(.*\')" % eag)` works too. Just had to get rid of ''